# What does this icon mean in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ide, xcode4.5

[image: Xcode Icon]

I have seen this icon on Xcode 4.5 whenever I run a project. I have also seen this possibly on older versions of Xcode also, though I can't remember distinctly.

What could this possibly mean?

*EDIT: The image was not previously loaded, have uploaded it now*

*EDIT 2:* I wanted to know about the number 3 which is coming in the left side of the image. I understand the "114" denotes the warnings". Apologies for the ambiguous explanation in the question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you have warnings.

In this case you have 114 compiler warnings!

Click on it and you'll be taken to the correct tab in the project explorer where you can start working on correcting them.

As for the number 3, again, click on it - it shows you the number of tasks it is running.

Just try clicking on things in Xcode, you'll find a lot more information about it that way.

Comment: @Abizem Thanks, but I have edited my question and wanted to know the what the number 3 on the left side of the image denotes.